# Get RACTuple from merged signals

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I don't have any idea how to merge a lot of signals and get results from a RACTuple, its seems to be like easy answer but I can't found that.

What we have for exmaple:

```
NSArray *a = @[@{@"k1":@"v1"},
               @{@"k2":@"v2"},
               @{@"k3":@"v3"},
               @{@"k4":@"v4"},
               @{@"k5":@"v5"},
               @{@"k6":@"v6"},
               @{@"k7":@"v7"}];
NSArray *b = @[@{@"kk1":@"vv1"},
               @{@"kk2":@"vv2"},
               @{@"kk3":@"vv3"},
               @{@"kk4":@"vv4"},
               @{@"kk5":@"vv5"},
               @{@"kk6":@"vv6"},
               @{@"kk7":@"vv7"}];
```

and

```
     RACCommand *command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
            RACSignal *s1 = [self adaptObjects:a];
            RACSignal *s2 = [self adaptObjects:b];
            return [[RACSignal merge:@[s1,s2]] map:^id(id value) {
                return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
                    [subscriber sendNext:value];
                    return nil;
                }];
            }];
        }];

        [[command execute:nil] subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *x) {
            NSLog(@"%@",x);
        }];
```

this operator `map` is wrong I know that, but this is for example

```
- (RACSignal *)adaptObjects:(NSArray *)objects {
    return [objects.rac_sequence.signal flattenMap:^RACStream *(id x) {
        return [self adaptObject:x];
    }];
}

- (RACSignal*)adaptObject:(NSDictionary*) x {
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {

       // some operations with data here

        [subscriber sendNext:x];

        return nil;
    }];
}
```

In NSLog I want to see tuple result with two arrays first - s1, second - s2
Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written a small example, hope it helps you.

```
NSArray *a = @[@{@"k1":@"v1"},
               @{@"k2":@"v2"},
               @{@"k3":@"v3"},
               @{@"k4":@"v4"},
               @{@"k5":@"v5"},
               @{@"k6":@"v6"},
               @{@"k7":@"v7"}];

NSArray *b = @[@{@"kk1":@"vv1"},
               @{@"kk2":@"vv2"},
               @{@"kk3":@"vv3"},
               @{@"kk4":@"vv4"},
               @{@"kk5":@"vv5"},
               @{@"kk6":@"vv6"},
               @{@"kk7":@"vv7"}];

- (NSArray<RACSignal *> *)rac_signalsFromArray:(NSArray *)array {
    NSMutableArray<RACSignal *> *signals = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
        [signals addObject:[RACSignal return:dict]];
    }
    return signals;
}

NSArray *Asignals = [self rac_signalsFromArray:a];
NSArray *Bsignals = [self rac_signalsFromArray:b];

NSArray *signals = [[NSArray arrayWithArray:Asignals] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:Bsignals];

[[RACSignal zip:signals] subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *tuple) {
    // tuple here
}];
```

Comment: Yes, Its nice example. I missed the fact that we can wrap any object to RACSignal by `return:` method. Thx